# Can I have multiple Swagger endpoints in a single Web API?

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

My Web API has four controllers: Login, Users, Products and Sales. There are also three different client applications and each of these just use a single controller. Administrators have an User Administration app, Managers have a Product management App and customers have a "Buy this" app. So, three different Web API's?
Well, no. As all controllers share the same database so we want it all contained in a single project. They also share some functionality in the background and all APIs also need to support the Login controller.
What I want is that my API has three different URLs:

- example.com/Users
- example.com/Products
- example.com/Sales

These should be three different Swagger endpoints, each with the Login controller. I just wonder if this is even possible or if I need three different projects to get this to work.

Comment: it should be possible, similar to different version document. but the challenge would be to separate controllers.

Comment: Maybe you could do it by [leveraging the versioning feature of Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I had to find [this post about multiple Swagger documents](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents) but I managed to get it to work.
It starts with the builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen() where you use options.SwaggerDoc() multiple times to create multiple documents.
Then, using app.UseSwaggerUI() you add multiple endpoints for each doc. specifying the related document names from the previous step.
And with each controller you add `[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "...")]` to link the controller to a specific document. Without it, they end up in all documents...
The result is that I now have a single project that holds multiple Swagger endpoints and thus multiple Web API's.

Comment: If the intention was to create three distinct Swagger documents, to give to different groups of people, I don't see this problem being solved. Adding multiple SwaggerDocs will just list every document in the [Select Definition] drop down list of documents, all sharing the same URL, but with different query parameters.

Comment: @Mort Actually, no. Multiple SwaggerDocs by themselves can be set to just show methods from a single group. By using e.g. [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "Sales")] to the method, that method only becomes available in the sales group. It worked for me as I now have different API's for my methods, each limited to their own functions.

Comment: As for the dropdown list with documents... That's just part of the Swagger UI. A single UI for the API overview is fine, but each document generates it's own endpoint for the API calls.